# Can I exchange Euro notes to DKK in Copenhagen (airport)?

Tags: europe, airports, money, exchange, copenhagen

As im traveling to Copenhagen this Friday (11-3) and I will be bringing some Euro notes and some DKK with me.

As it's not that much DKK and its too late now to order more from the bank is it possible to exchange Euro notes to DKK somewhere in copenhagen airport?

I won't be having a creditcard so that's no option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's an international airport, so of course there will be at least one currency exchange bureau there who'll change it for you. Rates likely will be pretty bad though, as they have a captive market... (IIRC there's one near the railway ticket machines, amongst other places)

Answer (score 6):

At the bottom of the [Shopping Services](https://www.cph.dk/en/Shopping-and-tax-free/shopping/stores/) page on the Copenhagen Airport web site, there is a section for "Banks and Currency Exchange". There are five American Express currency exchange offices listed which can be found in various places in the airport.

Comment: The most conveniently located exchange counters are probably the ones in the baggage reclaim hall. Otherwise, turn hard left immediately after clearing customs and hug the wall until you find the landside exchange counter.